# How to make model class for this json data

Tags: android, json, kotlin, jsonparser

How to make model for this json? I am facing issue in entry array, unable to make model for this entry array in the json data. How to get rid of this issue:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "im:name": {
          "label": "EquityValueMeasure"
        },
        "rights": {
          "label": "© FIRST SEAFRONT FINANCIAL LIMITED"
        },
        "im:price": {
          "label": "Get",
          "attributes": {
            "amount": "0.00",
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        },
        "im:image": [
          {
            "label": "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple112/v4/87/75/e5/8775e570-34fb-5762-3885-1a1c57eb09ea/AppIcon-0-0-1x_U007emarketing-0-0-0-5-0-0-sRGB-0-0-0-GLES2_U002c0-512MB-85-220-0-0.png/53x53bb.png",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "53"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple112/v4/87/75/e5/8775e570-34fb-5762-3885-1a1c57eb09ea/AppIcon-0-0-1x_U007emarketing-0-0-0-5-0-0-sRGB-0-0-0-GLES2_U002c0-512MB-85-220-0-0.png/75x75bb.png",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "75"
            }
          },
          {
            "label": "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple112/v4/87/75/e5/8775e570-34fb-5762-3885-1a1c57eb09ea/AppIcon-0-0-1x_U007emarketing-0-0-0-5-0-0-sRGB-0-0-0-GLES2_U002c0-512MB-85-220-0-0.png/100x100bb.png",
            "attributes": {
              "height": "100"
            }
          }
        ],
        "im:artist": {
          "label": "FIRST SEAFRONT FINANCIAL LIMITED",
          "attributes": {
            "href": "https://apps.apple.com/us/developer/first-seafront-financial-limited/id1637564433?uo=2"
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "label": "EquityValueMeasure - FIRST SEAFRONT FINANCIAL LIMITED"
        },
        "link": {
          "attributes": {
            "rel": "alternate",
            "type": "text/html",
            "href": "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/equityvaluemeasure/id1637564431?uo=2"
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "label": "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/equityvaluemeasure/id1637564431?uo=2",
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "1637564431",
            "im:bundleId": "Huta.Naguanzuomaca"
          }
        },
        "im:contentType": {
          "attributes": {
            "term": "Application",
            "label": "Application"
          }
        },
        "category": {
          "attributes": {
            "im:id": "6002",
            "term": "Utilities",
            "scheme": "https://apps.apple.com/us/genre/ios-utilities/id6002?uo=2",
            "label": "Utilities"
          }
        },
        "im:releaseDate": {
          "label": "2022-08-02T02:17:49-07:00",
          "attributes": {
            "label": "August 2, 2022"
          }
        }
      }
      ]
      
  }
}
```

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/newfreeapplications/limit=4/json
this is the api to get the full  json response.
Tried plugin for JSON to Kotlin class , getting error for some classes which has same object name but differ in pararams

Answer (score 0):

```
package modelClass

import com.beust.klaxon.*

private val klaxon = Klaxon()

data class Model (
val feed: Feed
) {
public fun toJson() = klaxon.toJsonString(this)

companion object {
    public fun fromJson(json: String) = klaxon.parse<Model>(json)
    }
}

data class Feed (
    val entry: List<Entry>
)

data class Entry (
   @Json(name = "im:name")
   val imName: IMName,

   val rights: IMName,

   @Json(name = "im:price")
   val imPrice: IMPrice,

   @Json(name = "im:image")
   val imImage: List<IMImage>,

   @Json(name = "im:artist")
   val imArtist: IMArtist,

   val title: IMName,
   val link: Link,
   val id: ID,

   @Json(name = "im:contentType")
   val imContentType: IMContentType,

   val category: Category,

   @Json(name = "im:releaseDate")
   val imReleaseDate: IMReleaseDate
)

  data class Category (
   val attributes: CategoryAttributes
   )

  data class CategoryAttributes (
     @Json(name = "im:id")
     val imID: String,

     val term: String,
     val scheme: String,
     val label: String
   )

   data class ID (
      val label: String,
      val attributes: IDAttributes
   )

   data class IDAttributes (
     @Json(name = "im:id")
     val imID: String,

     @Json(name = "im:bundleId")
     val imBundleID: String
    )

   data class IMArtist (
     val label: String,
     val attributes: IMArtistAttributes
   )

    data class IMArtistAttributes (
      val href: String
     )

   data class IMContentType (
       val attributes: IMContentTypeAttributes
      )

      data class IMContentTypeAttributes (
      val term: String,
      val label: String
     )

data class IMImage (
val label: String,
val attributes: IMImageAttributes
)

data class IMImageAttributes (
val height: String
 )

data class IMName (
val label: String
)

data class IMPrice (
val label: String,
val attributes: IMPriceAttributes
)

data class IMPriceAttributes (
val amount: String,
val currency: String
)

data class IMReleaseDate (
val label: String,
val attributes: IMName
)

data class Link (
val attributes: LinkAttributes
)

data class LinkAttributes (
val rel: String,
val type: String,
val href: String
)
```

Comment: Thanks Lalrem works fine with  @SerializedName("label") rather @Json

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help. Happy Coding.